# Bulk query insert in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am inserting record using bulk query from source table to destination table. Source table have 10,000 records. Suppose source table have a column `sid int`, `sname varchar(60)` and destination column have `sid int`, `sname varchar(30)`.

Now I was not able to insert all record successfully, as length problem in source `sname` and destination `sname`. As only few rows have a problem.

Now my question is that is there any way to insert record in destination table using bulk insert so that correct record is inserted and incorrect record is not inserted.

I am using c# 3.5

code which I am using

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(constring, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
        {
            try
            {
                //Edit mapping.
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("AddressID", "AddressID");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("AddressLine1", "AddressLine1");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");

                //specify destination table.
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Address]";

                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
                bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 100;
               // bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(bulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied);
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\n\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What mechanism are you currently using for the insert?

Comment: I am using bulk insert of SqlBulkCopy class.

Comment: You can take a look of code which I had provide to transfer data from one table to another in sql server

Answer (score 2):

Are you utilizing `BULK INSERT` through SQL Server, or are you using the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` class?

If you are using the `BULK INSERT` T-SQL, then you can just set `MAXERRORS` equal to whatever your desireble threshold is (the default is 10, which is why your `BULK INSERT is probably canceling out).

```
BULK INSERT YourDb.YourSchema.YourTable
   FROM 'c:\YourFile.txt'
   WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n',
         MAXERRORS = 1000        -- or however many rows you think are exceeding the 30 char limit
      )
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your are using the `SqlBulkInsert` class, I think your best bet would be to modify the `DataTable` before calling the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()` method:

```
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if (row["YourColumnThatExceeds30Chars"].ToString().Length > 30)
            row["YourColumnThatExceeds30Chars"] = 
                row["YourColumnThatExceeds30Chars"].ToString().Substring(0, 30);
    }
```

Comment: I am using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy class

Comment: Is source table have 30 columns then we can not check in this way. Its time consuming. Is there any other way as columns comes dynamically and length may be differ via table to table

Comment: @Awadhendra As far as I know, there is no built-in way to handle this through the `SqlBulkCopy` class.  Looking through the class members, there isn't a fix-all setting that you can apply.  This is one of those times where a poor design (input data is bigger than destination store) will consume time.

Comment: Saying it's time consuming is silly. This check is linear with respect to the size of data and cost nothing in terms of I/O. Your bulk insert takes orders of magnitude more time.